# windows phone xml parsing

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-7, xml-parsing

i have been working windows phone 7 application and i came across a problem while fetching a data from a webservice. im getting a responce from a server in such a pattern that i could not figure out how can i fetch it. please help me. below is the responce came from server.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<response xmlns="uri:abc.com" status="Ok" op="DelegateList" msg="Get Delegate List Successful">
<list count="19">
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12936">
<prop value="A" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="A" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Karachi, PK" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12938">
<prop value="aaa" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="aaaa" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="aa" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="aaaa" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="aa,aa" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12949">
<prop value="ad" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="ad" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="a,b" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12956">
<prop value="Asdsad" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Asdasd" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12955">
<prop value="asd" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Asdd" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12963">
<prop value="A" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="B" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12964">
<prop value="a" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="B" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12929">
<prop value="G" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="F" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Karachi, PK" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Arts & Music" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="1292620120724105446.jpg" id="12926">
<prop value="faraz" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="haider" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Team Leader Iphone at Cubix Labs Inc" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs Inc." name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Karachi, Pakistan" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="1292120120723075111.jpg" id="12921">
<prop value="cubix" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="labs" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="iphone developer at Social Cubix" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="Social Cubix" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="test,test" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12939">
<prop value="New" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="One" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Karachi, PK" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12961">
<prop value="E" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Qwe" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12957">
<prop value="s" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="S" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12965">
<prop value="dassd" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Sadds" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12960">
<prop value="Asfdcasscf" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Sff" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Dehli, India" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Architecture" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12922">
<prop value="Michael" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Tabour" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Software Engineer" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="Cubix Labs" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Maryland, United States" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="IT Services, Internet & Telecommunications" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="1292020120723075408.jpg" id="12920">
<prop value="test" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="test" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="test" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="test" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="test, test" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
<delegateinfo photoid="" id="12933">
<prop value="Test" name="fname" label="First Name"/>
<prop value="Test1" name="lname" label="Last Name"/>
<prop value="Coderu" name="ptitle" label="Professional Title"/>
<prop value="Xyz pvt ltd" name="company" label="Company"/>
<prop value="Karachi, PK" name="ccountry" label="Country / City"/>
<prop value="Airlines & Aviation" name="industry" label="Industry"/>
</delegateinfo>
</list>
</response>
```

code i used to fatch it and which is not given me any desired result:

```
XDocument ListArray= XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
 var quotes = from quote in ListArray.Descendants("response").Descendants("list").Descendants("delegateinfo").Descendants("prop")
                select new delegateinfo
     {

       lastName = quote.Attribute("value").Value
     };
                foreach (delegateinfo stockQuote in quotes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show (stockQuote.lastName);
                }
```

Comment: Why would you need there to be style information? What are you trying to do? What code have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: If it's a WebService why not add a WebReference and use the generated proxy classes to communicate? This way you don't even have to see the XML and have the use of strong types.

Comment: really strange structure

Comment: i have edited my question, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 List<delegateinfo> propList = new List<delegateinfo>();
            var list = document.Descendants().ElementAt(1);

            foreach (var tempVar in list.Descendants())
            {
                delegateinfo obj = new delegateinfo();
                foreach (var delegateinfo_ in tempVar.Descendants())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(delegateinfo_.Attribute("value").Value);
                    if (delegateinfo_.Attribute("label").Value.CompareTo("fname") == 1)
                        obj.firstName = delegateinfo_.Attribute("value").Value;
                    else
                        if (delegateinfo_.Attribute("label").Value.CompareTo("lname") == 1)
                            obj.lastName = delegateinfo_.Attribute("value").Value;
                    else
                            if (delegateinfo_.Attribute("label").Value.CompareTo("ccountry") == 1)
                                obj.country = delegateinfo_.Attribute("value").Value;
                    else
                                if (delegateinfo_.Attribute("label").Value.CompareTo("industry") == 1)
                                    obj.industry = delegateinfo_.Attribute("value").Value;


                    propList.Add(obj);




                }



            }
```